# How to determine all the angular 2 components have been rendered?

Tags: javascript, angular, domready

Is there an angular event which will be triggered when all the Angular2 components have finished rendering?

For `jQuery`, we can use

```
$(function(){ ... })
```

However, with Angular2, when the `domready` event is triggered, the html contains angular component tags only.  And after each component finished rendering, the `domready` event will be triggered again & again.

What we need is a final event when all the angular components have finished rendering.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [**ngAfterViewInit**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/AfterViewInit-class.html) on the root `AppComponent`? I'm sure all the components have been rendered by then. This is a hook that angular calls after it creates all the component's child views.

Answer (score 1):

you may check `ngAfterViewInit` applied on the root component.

> **ngAfterViewInit**    Respond after Angular initializes the component's
>   views and child views. Called once after the first
>   ngAfterContentChecked.

Read more about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#afterview).

Hope this helps!!